# VB.NET LINQ how to concatenate a Select

Tags: vb.net, linq

```
 Dim placesOfServces =  From x In tbl_pos _
                        Where x.active = True _
                        Select  x.pos_id, x.pos_code & " - " & x.pos_desc
```

Getting Error

> Range variable name can be inferred only from a simple or qualified name with no arguments.

Problem, need to return a concatenated string of `x.pos_code` and `x.pos_desc`. The help has to be in VB.NET.

Comment: tbl_pos is an entity from the entity framework.

Comment: Here is the answer ----  Dim placesOfServces =  From x In tbl_pos _               
        Where x.active = True _
        Select New With {.pos_id = x.pos_id, .pos_desc = x.pos_code & " - " & x.pos_desc}

Comment: You can answer your own question, btw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Dim placesOfServces =  From x In tbl_pos _
                        Where x.active = True _
                        Select New With {.Pos_id= x.pos_id , .CodeDesc = x.pos_code & " - " & x.pos_desc}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this:

```
 Dim placesOfServces =  From x In tbl_pos _                                       
                       Where x.active = True _
                       Let cc = x.pos_code & " - " & x.pos_desc   
                       Select  x.pos_id, cc
```